# Pulp optimization model not giving reasonable result?

Tags: python, optimization, pulp

I am trying to get an optimization model to decide on an optimal commitment rate. The general problem structure, in its simplest form, is as follows:

A known number of instances of known types is running for each hour over 10 hours. The number of each type running hour to hour is arbitrary, but known. For each of these instances, they have an on-demand rate and a savings plan rate, the latter being arbitrarily lower than the former. The rates vary depending on the type, but not hour to hour.

A dollar amount can be committed across all hours (only one commitment applies to all hours, cannot have different commitments per hour) s/t Commitment >= sum_over_all_types(# of instance type X * SP rate of instance type X) for that hour. Not all instances of same type need to utilize the SP rate. Ie if we have 4 A and 5 B for hour 1, its possible that the optimal to achieve full 'utilization' is 4 A and 1 B, or any other combo.

Also, if there is any hour s/t that sum_over_all_types([# instance]*[instance SP rate]) <= commitment rate, the cost for that hour is just equal to the commitment rate. If the sum is higher, than an optimal combination of the instances is chosen s/t the on-demand cost for that hour is minimized.

Any instances not 'part of'/'receiving' the SP rate will be charged the on-demand rate.

I have tried to set up the this optimization using PuLP as follows (with some example data):

```
from pulp import *

# Define input data
instances = {'A': {'on_demand': 10000.0, 'savings_plan': 0.0001},
             'B': {'on_demand': 2.0, 'savings_plan': 1.5},
             'C': {'on_demand': 3.0, 'savings_plan': 2.0}}

hourly_instances = {
    1: {'A': 5, 'B': 2, 'C': 1},
    2: {'A': 6, 'B': 3, 'C': 1},
    3: {'A': 7, 'B': 4, 'C': 2},
    4: {'A': 8, 'B': 5, 'C': 2},
    5: {'A': 9, 'B': 6, 'C': 3},
    6: {'A': 10, 'B': 7, 'C': 3},
    7: {'A': 11, 'B': 8, 'C': 4},
    8: {'A': 12, 'B': 9, 'C': 4},
    9: {'A': 13, 'B': 10, 'C': 5},
    10: {'A': 14, 'B': 11, 'C': 5}
}

# Define the model
model = LpProblem("Instance Optimization", LpMinimize)

# Define decision variables
commitment_rate = LpVariable("commitment_rate", lowBound=0)
savings_plan_utilization = {}
for hour in hourly_instances.keys():
    for instance_type in instances.keys():
        savings_plan_utilization[(hour, instance_type)] = LpVariable(f"savings_plan_utilization_{hour}_{instance_type}", cat='Binary')

# Define objective function
hourly_costs = []
for hour, instance_counts in hourly_instances.items():
    hourly_cost = lpSum([instances[type]['savings_plan'] * count * savings_plan_utilization[(hour, type)] for type, count in instance_counts.items()])
    hourly_cost += lpSum([instances[type]['on_demand'] * count for type, count in instance_counts.items() if instances[type]['savings_plan'] == 0])
    hourly_costs.append(hourly_cost)
model += lpSum(hourly_costs) + commitment_rate


# Add utilization constraints
for hour, instance_counts in hourly_instances.items():
    for type in instances.keys():
        model += savings_plan_utilization[(hour, type)] <= instance_counts[type]

# Add commitment rate constraint
model += lpSum([instances[type]['savings_plan'] * lpSum(savings_plan_utilization[(hour, type)] for hour in hourly_instances.keys()) for type in instances.keys()]) <= commitment_rate

# Print the solver status
print("Solver Status: ", LpStatus[model.status])


# Solve the model
model.solve()

# Print the values of the decision variables
for v in model.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

# Print the value of the objective function
print("Objective =", value(model.objective))


# Output the results
print(f"Optimal commitment rate: {commitment_rate.value()}")

# Output the savings plan utilization for each hour
for hour in hourly_instances.keys():
    print(f"Hour {hour} Savings Plan Utilization: {lpSum(savings_plan_utilization[(hour, type)] for type in instances.keys()).value()}")

# Calculate the hourly costs
hourly_costs = []
for hour, instance_counts in hourly_instances.items():
    hourly_cost = lpSum([instances[type]['on_demand'] * count for type, count in instance_counts.items()])
    hourly_cost += lpSum([instances[type]['savings_plan'] * count * savings_plan_utilization[(hour, type)].value() for type, count in instance_counts.items()])
    hourly_costs.append(hourly_cost.value())

# Calculate the optimized commitment rate
commitment_rate = lpSum([instances[type]['savings_plan'] * lpSum(savings_plan_utilization[(hour, type)] for hour in hourly_instances.keys()) for type in instances.keys()]).value()

# Output the optimized commitment rate
print(f"Optimized Commitment Rate: {commitment_rate}")

# Visualize the hourly costs and the optimized commitment rate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(1, len(hourly_costs)+1), hourly_costs, label='Hourly Cost')
plt.axhline(y=commitment_rate, color='r', linestyle='-', label='Optimized Commitment Rate')
plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.ylabel('$/hr')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

It keeps solving to an optimal commitment rate of $0... I don't understand why, since I have made it extremely attractive to run instance A via the SP rate ($0.0001/instance/hr vs $10000/instance/hr).

My hunch is that somehow using the SP rate is not removing the on-demand rate for that instance/hour. But I am not sure how to implement this specifically?

The 'optimal' solution the model gives me provides me with the following total cost:

[image: "Solution"]

Comment: I don't see a demand constraint:  i.e. a >= constraint. Without that using 0 is the cheapest.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Can you elaborate a bit further?

Comment: I had thought that my setup makes the number of instances being used static? I defined the number of instances per hour. Is this not sufficient? How is it possible that there is 0 a?

Comment: To expand on the other comment, all of the constraints you have are for the "upper limits" of what can be done in the system.  That's good.  What you don't have is any kind of constraint forcing anything to be done, and without that, the minimum cost is achieved by doing nothing for a cost of zero.

Comment: It's like leaving for the day and telling your kids there are 8 chores to be done so work efficiently while I'm gone....  Come home and 0 chores are done and they say, "Well, you didn't say that I had to actually do any of the 8!"  That is the situation you are in.  You need a "forcing" or demand constraint such that in each time period or overall or whatever (I didn't look to close) there is some constraint the the stuff gets done or assigned in some way.

Comment: I understand that conceptually, but the model's output total cost is not $0. The 'optimal' commitment rate it comes up with is $0, but not the total cost. It is the sum product of all [# of instances]*[on-demand rate]. In effect, it choosing to assign them all as on-demand. So its not like its somehow choosing to assign 0. Its like your kids did all of the chores without any tools.

Comment: lol....  ok.  I thought it was a hard zero.  lemme run it and take a look.  You must not have kids.... you never trust them with your tools!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252240/discussion-between-runeaway3-and-airsquid).

Comment: I stand by the original assessment.  You have no forcing function and nothing is done.  You have 2 constraints which are both "upper limits" ... the solution of zero across the board (which is what I get) is the optimal under those conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.  Here's a modest rework of what you had.  In this formulation, the cost in the objective function is the "forcing function" because the main decision variable is how many things to cover with the "level pay" (renamed) commitment, and the cost goes up to cover all of the things that are NOT covered by the level pay amount.

You had a binary variable in there which was confusing...  I think the right approach is an integer variable representing how many things are covered (by each type, in each time period) by the level pay amount, and then we know from there that the on-demand part is the remainder, which is in the cost/objective function.

This seems to work fine and the results pass the giggle test.  Be advised, the solver status shows optimal (what we are looking for), but the optimal value in the solver dialogue reflects a simplification the solver is doing by dropping the constant term from the objective function of 504.0, so it shows -203 for an actual optimal value of +301.0.

```
from pulp import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define input data
rates =     {'A': {'on_demand': 4.0, 'level_pay_rate': 1.6},
             'B': {'on_demand': 2.0, 'level_pay_rate': 1.5},
             'C': {'on_demand': 3.0, 'level_pay_rate': 2.0}}

hourly_demand = {
    1: {'A': 5, 'B': 2, 'C': 1},
    2: {'A': 6, 'B': 3, 'C': 1},
    3: {'A': 7, 'B': 4, 'C': 2},
    4: {'A': 8, 'B': 5, 'C': 2},
    5: {'A': 9, 'B': 6, 'C': 3},
    6: {'A': 10, 'B': 7, 'C': 3},
    7: {'A': 11, 'B': 0, 'C': 4},
    8: {'A': 12, 'B': 9, 'C': 4},
    9: {'A': 7, 'B': 10, 'C': 5},
    10: {'A': 3, 'B': 5, 'C': 5}
}

I = rates.keys()              # items
T = hourly_demand.keys()   # time periods

IT = {(i, t) for i in I for t in T}  # item-time tuples

# Define the model
model = LpProblem("level_pay_model", LpMinimize)

# Define decision variables
level_pay_amt = LpVariable("level_pay", lowBound=0)
level_pay = LpVariable.dicts('level_pay', IT, lowBound = 0, cat='Integer')  # the quantity of i in time t to buy with level-pay

# Define objective function: the aggregate cost of servicing all demands by either level pay or on-demand

# a helper function for the hourly cost
def hourly_cost(t):
    #      the level pay         the total of items not covered by level pay * on-demand cost
    return level_pay_amt + lpSum((hourly_demand[t][i] - level_pay[i, t]) * rates[i]['on_demand'] for i in I) 
model += lpSum(hourly_cost(t) for t in T)

print(model)
# alternate construct with out the function...
#model += lpSum(level_pay_amt + lpSum((hourly_demand[t][i] - level_pay[i, t]) * rates[i]['on_demand'] for i in I) for t in T)

# constraints
# 1. don't bust the level-pay dollars
for t in T:
    model += lpSum(level_pay[i, t] * rates[i]['level_pay_rate'] for i in I) <= level_pay_amt

# 2. limit the level-pay to the demand.... or else get funky negative results.
for i, t in IT:
    model += lpSum(level_pay[i, t]) <= hourly_demand[t][i]

solution = model.solve()

print(f'level pay amt: {level_pay_amt.varValue}')

for t in T:
    print(value(hourly_cost(t)))

for i,t in sorted(IT):
    print("level pay:", i, t, level_pay[i, t].varValue)

print()

# Visualize the hourly costs and the optimized commitment rate

cost_vec = [value(hourly_cost(t)) for t in sorted(T)]
plt.plot(sorted(T), cost_vec, label='Hourly Cost')
plt.axhline(y=value(level_pay_amt), color='r', linestyle='-', label='Level Pay Amt.')
plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.ylabel('$/hr')
plt.legend()
plt.title(f'Costs by Hour [Total Cost: ${value(model.objective) : 0.2f}]')
plt.show()

colors = list('rgb')
for color, i in enumerate(I):
    plt.plot(T, [level_pay[i, t].varValue for t in T], ls='--', color=colors[color], label=f'level pay {i}')
    plt.plot(T, [hourly_demand[t][i] - level_pay[i, t].varValue for t in T], ls='-', color=colors[color], label=f'on-demand {i}')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

##### Note...

To more fully explain the comment train...  An alternate formulation of this model is certainly possible (and maybe easier to understand) if you use separate variables for the "level pay" and "on demand" quantities.  If we forget about the different types of items and time periods this would be something like:

```
demand = 5  # units to deliver/purchase whatever

rates = {method_1 : 1.5, method_2 : 2.0}
```

then variables like:

```
deliver_1, deliver_2 ∈ Integers
```

objective like:

```
min:  deliver_1 * rates[method_1] + deliver * rates[method_2]
```

then the **forcing function**  or demand constraint to ensure everything is delivered/purchased whatever:

```
deliver_1 + deliver_2 >= demand
```

And likely other constraints to limit these activities in some way...

The formulation in the solution is slightly more advanced because this is a "one or the other" type of situation, so you really only have one variable and the other can be deduced from data, which keeps the model a bit more compact, generally desirable if the model gets "large."

Comment: This is truly excellent. I understand the changes you made, the rationale around the new constraints, and the note on a the 'easier to read' alternative function. However, I do not understand the note about the objective function's constant term. 

I can see that the total cost sums to 301. But I don't understand why the solver is subtracting 504 from this. When you say "constant term" I would imagine that this is the level pay sum, since this is constant hour to hour. But this would be 22.3*10, which is not 504. Can you explain this a bit further please?

Comment: Sure.  run the code as written above and examine the first thing to print...where I have `print(model)` right after the making of the objective.  It will print the equation and you will see the 504.  Where does it come from?  Well, if you look at the equation, it the `level_pay_amt` is a **variable**, so that is *not* it and you will see 10*`level_pay_amt` in the formula....  However, if you look at the rest of the equation it is `sum ( tot_demand - level_paid_items) * cost` in each tilmestep, so the`tot_demand` and `cost` are fixed, so this is just distribution property and it is the same

Comment: as `sum(tot_demand * cost) - sum(level_paid_items * cost)`.  That first summation is all known values ==> 504.  We are essentially seeing how much cost we can reduce from 504, which would be the cost if we on-demanded everything.  The solver throws out this fixed value

Comment: I attempted to run this with some real data (rather than sample) and even when severely truncating it I reach a `maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison`. The issue seems to be at line `return level_pay_amt + lpsum(hourly_demand[t][i] - level_pay[i, t]) * rates[i]['on_demand] for i in I)`. I don't understand why this is happening since my truncated data is only 3 time periods with 2 types.

Comment: Tough to troubleshoot without the whole thing.... but... try commenting out the line that calls the function and then un-commenting the "alternate objective" line that should produce the same model/result without using the function.  Try it on the small data, verify it is same output, and then try the larger dataset.  If this fails, you probably need to ask an additional/secondary question with more complete info and pop a comment in with my name and I'll find it.

Comment: In case you're curious.... my read_in_data script wasn't casting the strings to floats. Not sure why exactly that produced the described error, but properly casting the numerical values fixed it.

Comment: Ran into a different issue that could use your attention XD

Comment: Just noticed... it is possible my hourly demand is non-integer. Does this script account for that?